# Concurrent connections in C# socket

Tags: c#, sockets

There are three apps run at the same time, 2 clients and 1 server. The whole system should function as following:

- The client sends an serialized object to server then server receives that object as a stream, finally the another client get that stream from server and deserialize it.

This is the sender:

```
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);

            Stream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, event); // Event is the sending object

            tcpClient.Close();
```

Server code:

```
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
        listener.Start(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Server is running at localhost port 8888 ");

        while (true)
        {
            Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
            try 
            {
                Stream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
                // Typically there should be something to write the stream
                // But I don't knwo exactly what should the stream write
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected: {0}", socket.RemoteEndPoint);
            }
        }
```

The receiver:

```
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        // Connect the client to the localhost with port 8888
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
        Stream stream = client.GetStream();
        Console.WriteLine(stream);
```

when I run only the sender and server, and check the server, server receives correctly the data. The problem is when I run the receiver, everything is just disconnected. So where is my problem ? Could anyone point me out ? Thanks

Comment: How do you know if a client is a sender or a receiver? Perhaps the server should listen on two different ports? Or perhaps the receiver should be listening also and the server connect out to it.

Comment: Try using async sockets for situations where you can have multiple clients which are sending and receiving. Use functions like OnAccept(), OnRecieve() etc